# Убрать ненужные пиксели

Tags: php

Есть небольшой скрипт, он прогоняет через себя все пиксели некоторого изображения,  сохраняет в ассоциативный массив цвет пикселя и количество пикселей этого цвета.

Проблема в том что скрипт работает очень долго, потому что на картинке встречается огромное количество пикселей с таким цветом, который за всю картинку встречается всего один раз.

Можно ли перед прогонкой изображения или во время неё убрать эти ненужные пиксели что бы скрипт работал быстрее?

```
<?php
$image = 'img/rgb1.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($image);//открываем изображение

$sx = imagesx($img);//находим ширину
$sy = imagesy($img);//находим длину

$colors = array();//создаем массив в котором будем хранить все цвета которые есть на картинке
for ($y = 0; $y < $sy; $y++){
    $y_arr = array();
    for ($x = 0; $x < $sx; $x++){
        $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);

        $r = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
        $g = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
        $b = $rgb & 0xFF;

        $x_arr = array($r, $g, $b) ;
        $y_arr[] = $x_arr;
    }
    $colors[] = $y_arr; //заполнить массив значениями цветов пикселей
}


//поиск количества пикселей одинакового цвета
$color = array();//создаем массив который будет хранить цвета и их количество
$tm1 = array();//цвет
for ($i = 0; $i < $sx; $i++)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $sy; $j++)
    {
        $tmp = 0;//запоминаем количество цветов

        foreach ($color as $value){
            foreach ($value as $val) {
                if ($val == $colors[$i][$j] ) {  //проверка если в масcиве $color уже есть значение такого цвета
                    continue 3;                  //то вsходим из цикла и переходим к другому пикселю
                } else {
                    $tm1 = $colors[$i][$j];      //если такого цвета еще нет запоминаем его значение
                }
            }
        }
        //поиск количества цветов
        for ($ii = 0; $ii < $sx; $ii++)         //если был найден новый цвет то прогоняется веся картинках в поисках
        {                                       //пикселей с таким же цветом
            for ($jj = 0; $jj < $sy; $jj++)
            {
               if ($colors[$ii][$jj] == $tm1)
               {
                   $tmp++;                      // запоминается их количество
               }
            }
        }
        $color[] = [$tmp => $tm1];             //записывается в маcсив
    }
}

print_r($color);
```

Comment: Каким образом количество пикселей определенного цвета влияет на скорость работы скрипта? А если влияет, то скрипт плохой. Влияет общее количество пикселей.

Comment: Код то ваш где? Если количество огромно, то и работать будет не быстро. Пока вы не обработали все изображение, вы же не знаете, что там какой-то цвет встречается только один раз. Какую проблему вы вообще решаете?

Comment: @teran добавил код своего скрипта, подскажите что может быть не так, как можно оптимизировать?

Comment: Ну, цикл в цикле еще можно простить, раз у нас по сути матрица, но зачем внутри еще два цикла? Думаю, первым делом нужно убрать не нужные циклы.

Comment: в любом случае алгоритм будет линейным, так как вам обязательно нужно пройти каждый пиксель

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача решается за один проход, а тут проходов столько, сколько в картинке разных цветов: на каждый новый цвет вся картинка прогоняется заново в поисках этого цвета, хотя очевидно, что во все предыдущие пиксели не этого цвета.

Допустим, последний пиксель такого цвета, который еще не встречался. Так зачем же опять прогонять скрипт по все картинке, если пиксель последний и такого цвета еще не было? Очевидно, что пиксель такого цвета один.

Алгоритм должен быть такой:

1. взяли пиксель,
2. определили цвет,
3. увеличили значение в таблице цветов или добавили, если еще не было,
4. перешли к следующему.

Править код не буду, потому что тут надо заново писать, а не исправлять.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, благодаря вашему алгоритму скрипт работает на ура, но осталась проблема с ненужными пикселями, то есть, скрипт разрабатывается для того что-бы открыть картинку, найти сколько пикселей определенного цвета есть на картинке и в зависимости от этого делать расчет, но так как на картинке присутствуют оттенки цвета в одном экземпляре, и таких пикселей на всю картинку может быть много, что значительно уменьшает точность расчетов, так как они не будут учитываться, можно ли что-то сделать с этими единичными пикселями?

Comment: Можно, например, в конце пройтись по массиву с количеством цветов и обнулить те значение, которые меньше, например, 10 (или какое число лучше подойдет, зависит от размера изображения).

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение соседнего [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/938057/223826), если шибко не заботится о памяти,  то весь алгоритм подсчета сколько пикселей какого цвета в картинке, будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng( 'sample.png' );
$w = imagesx($img);
$h = imagesy($img);

$colors = [];
for($x = 0; $x < $w; $x++){
    for($y =0 ; $y < $h; $y++){
        $colors[] = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
    }
}


$result = array_count_values($colors);
arsort($result);


print_r($result);
```

Ключами будет цвет, значениями - сколько раз встречается. Отсортировано по частоте в порядке убывания. Чтобы получить составляющие цвета, можно использовать как битовые сдвиги (как у вас), либо `imagecolorsforindex($img, $color)`.

Очевидно, что если у вас будет картинка на 20Мпикселей черного цвета, то начальный массив будет содержать 20М элементов, вместо одного. Если хотите память расходовать более экономно, то `array_count_values` лесом, и считаем руками:

```
$c = imagecolorat($img, $x, $y);
if(array_key_exists($c, $colors)){
    $colors[$c]++;
}
else { $colors[$c]  = 1; }
```